# how to save variable and compare in another function

Tags: android

```
/* How to save object in a variable and send it to another function*/
     @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            int tappedapples=0;
            int colletedappels=0;
            // int mycollectedapples = 0;
            v.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            colletedappels = tappedapples;
            colletedappels++;
            txt.setText("" + colletedappels);
            Checkobjct(colletedappels);
        }
```

How to save object in a variable and send it to another function

Comment: You can make it a global variable if within same activity or use SharedPreference if in a different activity.

Answer (score 0):

```
    boolean compare(YourClass object1, YourClass object2)
    {
        return object1.equals(object2);
    }
```

Comment: and i want to compare it in another function

Comment: I updated my code. To be honest, I'm still confused. What do you wanna do exactly?

Comment: I have built an application and when user tapp on objects they disappear and i want to save them in a variable and then want to compare it in another function to see if user have collected the objects as required.

Comment: Do you mean 'views' by 'objects'?

Comment: Yes but it doesn't work properly how to do it my case.